# Controlling UINavigationItem content from within UINavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I am trying to programmatically set the contents of the `UINavigationItem` for the entire application from a central location (the View Controllers can then add their own buttons) within the `UINavigationController`, e.g.:

`viewDidLoad` method of the `UINavigationController`:

```
UINavigationItem *item = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login"];
[self.navigationBar pushNavigationItem:item animated:NO];
self.navigationItem.topItem.leftBarButtonItems = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: filterBtn, editBtn, nil];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: userBtn, infoBtn, mapsBtn, nil];
```

However, when calling `pushViewController` from a `UINavigationController`, the presented `UINavigationItem` gets set to default, with its title equal to the name of the scene.

```
[self pushViewController:viewController animated:NO];
```

Without calling `pushViewController` I am able to see my custom `UINavigationItem`.

The problem might be:

1. I'm using the `storyboard` to instantiate the view controller: `UIViewController *viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: screen];`
2. That instead of `push` I should be using `[self presentViewController:viewController animated:NO completion:nil]`, however, this method hides the navigation bar completely
3. A workaround might be to just present the `UIView`, but I'd rather avoid it for now.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever a `UIViewController` is pushed navigation items (left, middle, right) are replaced.

Navigation controller will push the default items if custom items (left, middle, right) has not been set of the `UIViewController`.

In your case what you can do is, Implement the `UINavigationControllerDelegate` within the `UINavigationController` and implement this method `navigationController(UINavigationController, willShow: UIViewController, animated: Bool)` method. And you can assign default navigation items just before pushing the `UIViewController`. And can also check if any custom item has been set or not.

```
func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {

    if viewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem == nil { // viewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems
        // assign default item
    }

    if viewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem == nil { // viewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems
        // assign default item
    }

    if viewController.navigationItem.titleView == nil {
        // assign default item
    }
}
```

You can also have a look at the official documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller). See section **The Left Item** and own-words.

**Option 2**

Create a `BaseViewController` and inherit all your view with `BaseViewController`. And then in `BaseViewController` you can set all the default navigation items.

```
class BaseViewController : UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: filterBtn, editBtn, nil];
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: userBtn, infoBtn, mapsBtn, nil];
    }
}
```